# Laravel 5 render() pagination error

Tags: laravel, pagination, laravel-5

1. `->render()` work fine.
2. I run: composer require illuminate/html
3. set `config/app.php`
4. add providers

   ```
   'Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider',
   'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',
   ```
5. add aliases

   ```
   'Form'      => 'Illuminate\Html\FormFacade',
   'Html'      => 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade',
   ```
6. now, `->render()` do not work, I try `->render()` with `{!! !!}` and `<?php ?>`

   ```
   Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
   1/1
   FatalErrorException in LengthAwarePaginator.php line 126:

   Access to undeclared static property: Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator::$presenterResolver

   1. in LengthAwarePaginator.php line 126
   2. at HandleExceptions->fatalExceptionFromError(array('type' => '1', 'message' => 'Access to undeclared static property: Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator::$presenterResolver', 'file' => 'C:\wamp\www\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator.php', 'line' => '126')) in compiled.php line 1721
   3. at HandleExceptions->handleShutdown()
   ```

Comment: Did you run `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: Does not work, I'm stuck, thanks :'(

Comment: I'm having this issue on prod server...  Works on homestead. Not trying to include the other packages either though.

Answer (score 0):

Check your local and remote Laravel version by using `artisan -v | grep version`.

In my case, they were different. I had a hard time updating it to match my local though. I didn't catch it because `composer update` results to `Nothing to install or update` even if I had cleared composer cache by `composer clear-cache` and reinstalling all the dependencies in the `vendor` folder.

I ended up deleting the whole project directory and cloning from source.

Answer (score 0):

Something is still out of date...
check version as suggested using:
   `php artisan -V`

and compare with https://github.com/laravel/laravel

In my situation i was need to delete:   `compiled.php` in `storage` dir

then run `composer update -vvv`

and ... error disrepair :-)

Answer (score 0):

The $compiledPath variable has been changed in the 5.0.16 release.

To solve your problem, you need to update $compiledPath variable in your bootstrap/autoload.php file to:

```
$compiledPath = __DIR__.'/../vendor/compiled.php';
```